# What are the different dialects that can be used in drools?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, rule-engine, dialect

I am making a framework of rules (in my spring boot application)that will fire automatically everyday.
However, the task of defining the rules is rested in the hands of the sales team who does not have any knowledge of java.

For now, I am using DROOLS and hence wanted to understand if there is any simple language dialect that can be used for writing the .drl file.

If not then kindly suggest if there are any other options available for my scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using a [Domain Specific Language](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.14.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_domain_specific_languages) - it's a way to match natural language expressions with Drools expressions so that a person with no programming knowledge can write rules. However, the DSL itself will have to be created and maintained by a person with technical skills.

Answer (score 0):

They can use Decision tables, which are simple spreadsheets with rules. See Drools documentation here [1]. Or they can use DMN. Drools now contains a DMN engine, however visual modeller is currently not available. However they could use third party tools, e.g. from Trisotech to model the DMN files visually. In this case the result is not a DRL file. With Decision tables, they are internally converted to DRL as far as I remember.

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.15.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#decision-tables-con_decision-tables
[2] https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.15.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#drools.DMN